# Importing a variable from a function?

Tags: python, function, import

My problem is that I want to use a variable from a def function, I don't know how to do it or if I even can. Here's the code I'm using

```
def yandn(prompt='Y/N:'):
    no=1
    while no==1:
      ok=input(prompt)
      if ok.lower()==('y'):
        a=0
        b=0
        break
    elif ok.lower()==('n'):
      a=1
      b=0
print('Blah Blah Blah')
c=1
while c==1:
  d=input('Blah Blah:')
  if d.lower() in valid:
    print('Confirm', d, 'as blah.')
    yandn()
    from yandn import a
    if a==1:
      c=1
    else:
      c=0
```

Comment: You could 'return a' from yandn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't import from function. There is 2 way you can achieve the same, 1 is through global variable, the other 1 is to return variable a from the function which is more recommended.

Using global variable

```
a = None # initialize global var
def yandn(prompt='Y/N:'):
    global a # indicate a as global var
    # continue with function code

yandn()
# no need import, now var a is accessible
```

Using return

```
a = yandn()
# you got the var a from yandn function now
```

Comment: "global variable 'a' is undefined at the module level"

Comment: before function `yandn` is called, global var `a` does not exist, you can initialize it outside the function with `a=None`

Comment: But c=1 so that it can be the catalyst for the while loop, I'm trying to make c=0 when a=1 and a is in the function yandn, I'm trying to do this so that I can save space on my code and not do tedious "if y==1" constantly.
P.S the last comment was removed because I felt it would cause confusion.

Comment: i still can't get what you mean, after added `global a` in function yandn and remove the line `from yandn import a`, what are the thing that not works now ?

Comment: Never mind, I understand now thanks to both of your answers, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No. You can't import things from a function. Why not have `yandn` *return* a?